# Implement this math Equation in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

How can I implement this math Equation in javascript:

> x + 2x + 3x +...+ nx = 100

Actually, I want to find the value of **x** but I want a code with the flexibility to define how many x we have ...

I have tried this with no luck:

```
var x;
for (var n = 1; n <= 10, n++){
     var cal = 100;
     cal += (n * x)
     console.log(cal)
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `cal = 0` before the loop.

Comment: You need to give a value to `x`.

Comment: There are some bugs here. Firstly, x is never assigned a value so you're multiplying n by undefined. Also, you're resetting cal on every iteration to 100, which I don't think you want to be doing either.

Comment: Writing a for loop that uses `x` won't work since `x` is the unknown. You need to turn this into a formula that solves for x.

Comment: Which is basically a high school algebra problem, not a programming problem. So [math.se] would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rewrite your equation as the following, you can make your algorithm a little simpler:

```
x*(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n) = 100
```

Now, as you want to find the value of `x` you can make `x` the subject:

```
x = 100 / (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)
```

So, the unknown thing here which is preventing you from calculating the value of `x` is the sum of all numbers from 1 to `n` (ie: `(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)`). We can use a `for` loop to calculate this value, and then use that to evaluate the value of `x`:

```js
var sum = 0;
var n = 4;
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  sum += i;
}
var x = 100 / sum;
console.log(x);
```

However, you can do this more efficiently. You could take advantage of the fact that the sum of a number `n` from 1 to `n` is:

```
sum(n) = n*(n+1)/2
```

Thus, you can factor out `x` and use this in your equation:

```
x*sum(n) = x*(n*(n+1)/2)
```

So, your equation is effectively:

```
x*(n*(n+1)/2) = 100
```

And making `x` the subject (by dividing both sides by `(n*(n+1)/2)`) will give you:

```
x = 100 / (n(n+1)/2)
```

Thus, we can use the above formula to calculate the value of `x`:

```js
const n = 4;
const x = 100 / (n*(n+1)/2);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations . just one question: how did you get `x*(n*(n+1)/2) = 100` from `x*sum(n) = x*(n*(n+1)/2)`?

Comment: @SaraRee yeah, from `x*sum(n) = x*(n*(n+1)/2)`. You can think of `sum(n)` as being `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`. As we defined, `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` is  `n*(n+1)/2`, so, your equation is simply `x*(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n) = 100`, which can be written as `x*(n*(n+1)/2) = 100`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be `x = 100 / (n * (n + 1) / 2)`, refer [Arithmetic Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

```js
n = 4;
x = 100 / (n * (n + 1) / 2);
console.log(x);
```